# Jquery UI: clone the widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to dynamically create the Jquery UI widget. 
My idea is to have a widget hidden and use the function clone() for create them.. but the result I get is this: [example](http://jsbin.com/enucip/)

What's wrong?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known problem](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui/browse_thread/thread/a1cbbd784aa0dae2?pli=1). The associated jQuery UI feature request can be found [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3803).

This feature would require cooperation from all the jQuery UI widgets (through modifications to their `init()` methods). The dev team does not seem to be interested in implementing that now, though they might do so in the future.

Comment: The only trick I know of is to clone the element and create a new widget on the clone, i.e. in your case call `slider()` on the cloned element with the same options as for the original element.