# How to properly clone buttons (and other things) using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Have a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/9NXHq/15/

It starts with one button defined via HTML. I then clone that button using jQuery, change the text, and add it after the original button. Notice how the new button's display is all messed up? But when you click the button, which causes the icon to be changed, it cleans itself up! What's the proper way to clone elements which have already been jQueried?

For instance, imagine a list of data and an "Add" button. Clicking add clones an entire row of data (from a hidden template row, for example) which includes jQueried elements such as buttons, auto-completes, etc. How should the elements in this new row be "reconstituted" to ensure that they work properly?

**HTML**

```
<a id="btn">This is a button.</a>​
```

**CSS**

```
/* Standard jQuery UI (1.8.16 in this case). */
```

**JavaScript**

```
/* Standard jQuery (1.7.1 in this case). */

var btn = $("a#btn");
var btn2 = null;

btn.button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-plus" } });
btn.click(function ()
{    
    $(this).button({ label: "Clicked!", icons: { primary: "ui-icon-check" } });
});

btn2 = btn.clone();
btn2.click(function ()
{    
    $(this).button({ label: "Clicked! (2)", icons: { primary: "ui-icon-check" } });
});                   
btn2.text(btn2.text() + " (2)");
btn2.insertAfter(btn);

//Need to re-constitue btn2 as a button.
btn2.button();
```

Comment: It doesn't look messed up to me (Safari 6).  What browser are you using?

Comment: Looks fine on Chrome (v23 on OSX)

Comment: It looks good on Chrome and IE9 on Windows.

Comment: Works in Opera, too. Btw, by cloning that button you create a second element with the same id, which should not happen.

Comment: As Bergi said, remember to give it a new id. Also, you might want to look into using the jquery on() instead of adding handlers for each one.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: hm, with clone(true) it really acts strange

Comment: confirmed OP's fiddle have a problem - no icon on it

Comment: [jquery-ui-clone-the-widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792558/jquery-ui-clone-the-widget) seems no hope

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The layout of the button is messed up (e.g. the original icon and text are treated as the text of the new button).

Comment: may be [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/9NXHq/22/) would be good for you...

Comment: @eicto I've been thinking something similar, keeping the template in JS instead of HTML. I may end up doing this sort of thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember trying to do this myself. This was the solution I settled with.

```
// Get source buttons options.. for icons and stuff. 
var btn_options = btn.button('option');

// Clone the button, change the ID, and re-init the button. 
var btn2 = btn
  .clone()
  .attr("id", "btn2")
  .button(btn_options);
```

I tried .clone(true) but it ends up with all the binded events of the previous one. .button() simply does too much thing to just be able to .clone it, I found it easier to just copy the settings and reinit it.

This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9NXHq/23/

Comment: I think that's a good recommendation. Another thing I've done is clone the button, then on the new button: `btn2.button("destroy"); btn2.removeData("button"); btn2.button(btn.button('options'))`.

Comment: My related question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865754/jquery-clone-copies-data-sometimes