# jQuery clone() copies data...sometimes...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, clone

Using the sample below, I have a `tr` that I am duplicating. It contains a jQuery `autocomplete`. The first time it is cloned, the auto complete functionality does not work because the attached `data("items")` is null. The second time the Add button is clicked, the autocomplete works. Thereafter, clicking Add once again produces a non-functioning autocomplete.

Adding a breakpoint inside of the `makeAutoComplete` function shows that `items` is always null except for when clicking Add the second time!

Can anyone explain this strange behavior?

**HTML/JS** (Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SDvF4/12/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test!</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            tr.Template
            {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                var textbox = $(".AutoComplete");

                makeAutoComplete(textbox);

                $("#addButton").click(function ()
                {
                    var attrRegex = /\d+/;
                    var template = $("tr.Template");
                    var newRow = template.clone(false);
                    var newRowIndex = (template.siblings().length + 1);

                    newRow.removeClass("Template");
                    newRow.find("*[id]").each(function ()
                    {
                        var element = $(this);

                        element.attr("id", element.attr("id").replace(attrRegex, newRowIndex));
                    });
                    newRow.find("*[name]").each(function ()
                    {
                        var element = $(this);

                        element.attr("name", element.attr("name").replace(attrRegex, newRowIndex));
                    });
                    newRow.insertBefore(template);
                    newRow.find(".AutoComplete").each(function ()
                    {
                        makeAutoComplete($(this));
                    });
                });
            });

            function makeAutoComplete(textbox)
            {
                var items = textbox.data("items");
                var test = textbox.data("test");

                if (items == null)
                {
                    if (test == "JSM")
                        alert("ERROR: data.items not copied but data.test was!");
                    else
                        alert("ERROR: data.items not copied nor was data.test!");
                }

                textbox.autocomplete(
                {
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: items
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="Template">
                    <td>
                        <input id="test_0" name="test_0" class="AutoComplete" type="text"/>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            var testData = [{ label: "One", value: 1 }, { label: "Two", value: 2 }];

                            $("#test_0").data("items", testData);
                            $("#test_0").data("test", "JSM");
                        </script>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br/><br/>

        <button id="addButton">Add</button>​
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using wrong IDs. They start with `-1` and also become `0`, which is what the template ID is. Use `+ 1` instead of `- 1` for `newRowIndex`. Not sure why `.clone()` exposes different behaviour because of this, though.

Comment: Thanks, good find. That explains why the 2nd clone worked and the others didn't - it had the same ID as the template but appeared before it.

Comment: Both data attributes are never copied over - You are using `.clone(false)` - from docs it states `A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the elements.`

Comment: It seems a bug. I've boiled it down to the following: http://jsfiddle.net/SDvF4/5/. Click the button, and see that after `insertBefore` the data is magically available. Also, this does **not** happen if you move the `<script>` block out of the `<td>` (which should not have any side effect). If you select `jQuery (edge)` then the issue disappears altogether, so it has been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: @pimvdb - interesting...trying it...

Comment: @wirey - `.clone(false)` does copy the data, as you can see here (http://jsfiddle.net/SDvF4/10/). @pimvdb has pointed out a strange occurrence regarding the data of an element before/after it's attached to the DOM.

Comment: @pimvdb - working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SDvF4/10/ attaching the element to the DOM before attempting to access its data seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple issues I had to fix to get this to work.

First was pointed out by @pimvdb - I wasn't IDing the elements correctly so the second new row had the same ID as the template row.

Second, you can't simply call `autocomplete` on a widget that is already an `autocomplete` - first you have to destroy it:

```
textbox.autocomplete("destroy");
textbox.removeData("autocomplete");
```

The 12th revision works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/SDvF4/12/